# How do I create a batch job for spark service under Bluemix

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

How do I create a batch job for spark service under Bluemix.

I need to process billion records in the text file , each record needs to be processed through a Java API. I would be interested to perform this with distributing the work over the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Stay tuned, should be able to run batch jobs on Bluemix Apache Spark service during the beta. Not there yet.

Comment: Randy , would it be possible to provide some more insights what I can expect with the present state of the service ,is it like only interactive spark shell based scripting could be done ?

Comment: Sorry Gaurav! You should expect to do batch and interactive.

Comment: Thanks Randy for the reply , for some reason I am not able to understand how to go for batch , I came to know that recently Spark service has made to GA , may be I need to take a look at it , in case it is able to help me.

Comment: @Gaurav, you may need to wait a little longer ;-)